# Regression's nomenclature problem

Tags: regression, econometrics

I'm reviewing the estimation of the parameters of a regression and a question arises regarding the nomenclature used by the book (Hansen's book).
The author considers it valid to write expressions such as the following:
$$E(e_i)=0$$
$$S(b)=E(y_i-x_ib)^2$$
$$b=(E(x_ix_i')^1E(x_iy_i))$$

where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are the observations for the i$th$ individual. $e_i$ is the error for the i$th$ individual. $b$ is the population parameter of the regression and $s(b)$ is the minimizer of the expected squared error.

Does it make sense to use the expected value for observations in these cases?- shouldn't it be used only in the model with random variables $X$ and $Y$?

For example, the expected value of the error of an observation should be the error of the observation and not 0.

Comment: $y_i$ is often considered a random variable for such derivations. Its distribution depends on $x_i$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand your claim that *the expected value of the error of an observation should be the error of the observation and not 0* - the claim is erroneous.

The expected value of $e_i$ is a number.  The error term $e_i$ is a random variable, whose possible values can be described by a distribution centered about the expected value $E(e_i)$ (in this case, 0).

I agree with you that the notation is not the best. If you denote the outcome variable by Y and the predictor variable by X, then you can use the following notation to refer to the observations you would expect to get from your $n$ subjects on these variables *before* you actually conduct the study and collect the data:  $(X_i, Y_i), i = 1, ..., n$.  You can formulate your model for these observations as: $Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1*X_i + \epsilon_i$, where $\epsilon_i$ is a random error term with expected value 0 and unknown variance $\sigma^2$.

Once the study is conducted and the data on $X$ and $Y$ are collected for the $n$ subjects, you can refer to the *observed* values of $(X_i, Y_i), i = 1, ..., n$ as $(x_i, y_i), i = 1, ..., n$. You are right that there is nothing random about these observed data values - they are known realizations of the random variables $(X_i, Y_i), i = 1, ..., n$. If something is fully known, it can't be random!

Comment: My claim: A observation is a realization of a random variable, therefore is a real number. The expected value of that number is itself. That is to say $E(e_i)=e_i$ Or in this case the observations are random variables?

Comment: The context leaves no ambiguity. The author is probably just using $e_i$ both for realization and random variable. But in the context - as you say - it would not make sense when taking expectation that $e_i$ is realization, hence reading the author in good spirit (assuming what he says makes sense) he must be using $e_i$ in that specific context as random variable. Not everyone always follows the convention of writing the random variable in capital letters.